# Como persistir informações de desconto progressivo?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Tenho uma situação na qual existe a seguinte regra de negócio: ao utilizar o sistema para realizar um pedido é possível colocar um desconto progressivo que se dá adicionando um número variável de porcentagens de desconto que são aplicadas sucessivamente.

Ou seja, é possível informar na sequência, por exemplo: 5, 10, 15, representando que primeiramente se aplica um desconto de 5%, depois de 10% e finalmente de 15%.

Fazer isso em código é simples, mas estou tendo problema para persistir esses dados. O problema aqui é o fato do número de descontos ser arbitrário. Por exemplo: é possível informar 3 descontos sucessivos, ou então 5, ou mesmo 10.

Se houvesse um número fixo de descontos que sempre são aplicados me parece que seria fácil salvar isso num banco de dados relacional. Bastaria criar uma tabela para os descontos, uma coluna para cada desconto.

No caso concreto, cheguei a pensar em `NoSQL` por conta da flexibilidade de não ter que definir uma tabela. Mas fiquei um pouco em dúvida, porque pelo pouco que sei sobre o assunto (ainda não estudei a fundo), me parece que seria matar uma formiga com uma bomba atômica. Além disso, existem vários tipos diferentes de `NoSQL` e eu não sei bem qual se aplicaria aqui.

Dessa forma, qual seria a maneira mais adequada de persistir esse tipo de dado?

Answer (score 3):

Se um pedido pode ter N descontos, você pode usar uma tabela `descontos` mais ou menos assim:

```
id   pedido_id    valor_desconto
--------------------------------
1            1                 5
2            1                10
3            1                15
4            2                 5
...
```